# How to simplify the sum: $\sum_{m_1+...+m_L=n}\prod_{i=1}^L(t_i)^{m_i}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$$\sum_{m_1+ ... +m_L=n}\prod_{i=1}^L(t_i)^{m_i}$$
where $t_i$ are real numbers between $[0, 1]$ and $n$ is a positive integer. $m_i$ are integers and $0 \le m_i \le n$.

The $\sum_{m_1+...+m_L=n}$ makes it complicated and hard to compute. I am looking for a way to get rid of the $\sum_{m_1+...+m_L=n}$ without making it too complex.

At first by intuition I thought it was the expansion of $\left(\sum_{i=1}^L{t_i}\right)^n$ but obviously I was wrong. For example, when $L=2$ and $n=3$, $t_1t_1t_2$ is counted once in the original series but is counted three times in $\left(\sum_{i=1}^L{t_i}\right)^n$ as $t_1t_1t_2$, $t_1t_2t_1$ and $t_2t_1t_1$. I can't figure out how to deal with such repetition. Perhaps this direction is totally wrong.

Is there any way to get rid of the $\sum_{m_1+...+m_L=n}$?

**Edit:** Some other given conditions (maybe useful):

1. $t_i$ are not necessarily distinct. There are some $t_i=t_j$ and $i \neq j$.
2. All the $t_i$ are in the set $\{\frac{1}{s}, \frac{2}{s} ... \frac{s-1}{s}\}$, where $s$ is a known positive integer.
3. All the $t_i$ are known so we know how many $t_j$ equal to $t_i$.

Comment: If I understand this object correctly, it is rather a finite sum than a series. Although of course every finite sum is a series.

Comment: Yes, it is a sum. Sorry I didn't pick words that precisely. Already modified.

Comment: Not a big deal. But it is probably better for reference purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easier to find a generating function for this value. This is the coefficient of $z^n$ in the expansion of:

$$\prod_{i=1}^L \frac{1}{1-t_iz}$$

You might be able to solve this, then, by using partial fractions:

$$\sum_{j=1}^L \frac{a_j}{1-t_jz} = \prod_{i=1}^L \frac{1}{1-t_iz}$$

Where the $a_j$ are some rational(?) functions of the $t_i$.

Not sure how that actually works out. If $L=2$, the value $a_1=\frac{t_1}{t_1-t_2}$ and $a_2=\frac{t_2}{t_2-t_1}$ and therefore we get:

$$\frac{1}{(1-t_1z)(1-t_2z)} = \frac{t_1}{t_1-t_2}\frac{1}{1-t_1z} + \frac{t_2}{t_2-t_1}\frac{1}{1-t_2z}$$

The coefficient of $z^n$ here is then $\frac{t_1^{n+1}-t_2^{n+1}}{t_1-t_2}$, which is sort of obvious in retrospect.

From Did's note below,

$$a_i=\prod_{j\neq i} \frac{t_i}{t_i-t_j}=t_i^{L-1}\prod_{j\neq i}\frac{1}{t_i-t_j}$$

So the coefficient of $z^n$ is:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{L} \frac{t_i^{n+L-1}}{\prod_{j\neq i}(t_i-t_j)}$$

So when $L=3$, this is:

$$\frac{t_1^{n+2}}{(t_1-t_2)(t_1-t_3)} + \frac{t_2^{n+2}}{(t_2-t_1)(t_2-t_3)} + \frac{t_3^{n+2}}{(t_3-t_1)(t_3-t_2)}$$

As noted in comments below, this assumes the $t_i$ are distinct. When some of the $t_i$ are equal, you have to take limits, which can be trick. For example, when $t_1=t_2$ and the rest are distinct, we need to compute the limit just for the first two terms in the above sum:

$$\lim_{t_2\to t_1} \left(\frac{t_1^{n+L-1}}{\prod_{j\neq 1} (t_1-t_j)}+\frac{t_2^{n+L-1}}{\prod_{j\neq 2} (t_2-t_j)}\right)$$

Defining $p(z)=(z-t_3)(z-t_4)\dots(z-t_L)$ and re-arranging, which are trying to find the limit of:

$$\frac{1}{t_1-t_2} \left(\frac{t_1^{n+L-1}}{p(t_1)}-\frac{t_2^{n+L-1}}{p(t_1)} + t_2^{n+L-1}\left(\frac{1}{p(t_1)}-\frac{1}{p(t_2)}\right)\right)$$

And as $t_2\to t_1$ we can show this limit is:

$$\frac{(n+L-1)t_1^{n+L-2}}{p(t_1)} - \frac{t_1^{n+L-1} \frac{p'(t_1)}{p(t_1)}}{p(t_1)}$$

But $\frac{p'(t_1)}{p(t_1)} = \frac{1}{t_1-t_3}+\frac{1}{t_1-t_4}\dots +\frac{1}{t_1-t_L}$

So the limit is:

$$\frac{1}{\prod_{i\neq 1,2} (t_1-t_i)}\left((n+L-1)t_1^{n+L-2} - t_n^{n+L-1}\left(\sum_{i\neq 1,2} \frac{1}{t_1-t_i}\right)\right)$$

That's just what replaces the first two terms, the other terms stay the same, except that $t_2$ is replaced by $t_1$.

For example, when $t_1=t_2=2$ and $t_3=3$ and $t_4=4$, the formula gives you:

$$(n+6)2^{n+1} - 3^{n+3} + 4^{n+2}$$

This is going to get very messy in dealing with the general cases where more $t_i$ can be equal.

Comment: $1/a_i=\prod\limits_{j\ne i}(1-t_j/t_i)$.

Comment: Thanks, @Did, forgot how to solve that generally.

Comment: Just saw your last edit. Thank you very much. @ThomasAndrews

Comment: You can probably prove this more directly by induction on $L$. More fun this way, though.

Comment: Also, I'm treating these as indeterminate $t_i$. If there are not necessarily distinct, you have additional problems.

Comment: Hi @ThomasAndrews, thank you. Unfortunately, $t_i$ are not necessarily distinct. I added three more conditions to describe my question more precisely. I am sorry I didn't mention that there are some $t_i=t_j \wedge i \neq j$. I thought it won't affect the result whether $t_i$ are distinct or not when I posted my question.

Comment: It's trickier with non-distinct $t_i$ because the partial fraction technique requires powers of $\displaystyle{\frac{a_{i,k}}{(1-zt_i)^k}}$.

Comment: When the $t_i$ are not distinct, you can do a limit, and that will give you the result you expect. For example, in the case when $L=3$ as $t_2\to t_1$ it converges to $$\frac{(n+2)t_1^{n+1}}{t_1-t_3} + \frac{t_3^{n+2}}{(t_3-t_1)^2}$$

Comment: Well, not exactly that, but something close. :)

Comment: Good idea @Thomas. I am trying to see if we can get a general form of this problem... As I mentioned in my question, all the $t_i$ are in the set $\{\frac{1}{s}, \frac{2}{s} ... \frac{s-1}{s}\}$, where $s$ is a known positive integer. So actually we can group $t_i$ by their values. If we know the number of $t_i$ equal to $\frac{k}{s}$ is $g_k$, can we get a general form of the result? Of course $\sum g_k = L$ here.

Comment: I am afraid that we couldn't generalize the result. The result can't make it correct when $L=3$ and $t_1=t_2=t_3$, which should be $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}t_1^n$ even with the limitation idea... (Perhaps I am wrong and just can't find the right way.)

Comment: @TomSmith It would definitely work with the limit, but it is harder. A lot harder.

Comment: I think the formula for $t_1=t_2=t_3$ should be $\frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{2}t_1^n$. The formula for $t_1=t_2$ is rightly:$$\frac{(n+1)t_1^{n+2}-(n+2)t_1^{n+1}t_3+t_3^{n+2}}{(t_1-t_3)^2}$$ You can use L'Hopital's rule, differentiating the numerator and denominator with respect to $t_3$ twice to get the value when $t_1=t_2=t_3$, and you get $\frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{2}t_1^n$.

Comment: Hi @ThomasAndrews, thanks a lot! I think it goes even more complicated than the original form when there are more $t_i$ equal to each other. Maybe this is all we can do...

Comment: @TomSmith Yes, it gets harder. It is still just linear algebra - you have to solve the partial fractions problem, which is just solving a system of linear equations. They are just really simple linear equations when all the $t_i$ are the different.

Comment: There is a recursive solution to this. Essentially, the partial fraction equation means to add another $t_i$ you need to be able to solve the partial fraction $\frac{1}{(1-t_1z)(1-t_2z)^k}$ when $t_1\neq t_2$. So you get a partial fraction solution for the entire equation inductively. That in turn gives you the explicit formula. But it's still messy as hell.